# While hatch means "to emerge from an egg", is there an equivalent word for "to emerge from a crysalis or cocoon"

Tags: verbs

Other than "to emerge", "to come out" or "to climb out", is there a specific verb that means "to emerge out of a chrysalis" or "to emerge out of a cocoon", like there is "to hatch" for "to emerge out of an egg"?

Comment: @Josh61 I've edited my answer to include usage from academic contexts, even though I'm not sure what that has to do with the question. Hopefully that helps you. Enjoy!

Comment: @Josh61 Fair enough, I didn't see that in the original question. Either way, Google Scholar returns a bunch of interesting results for eclosion! I don't think your answer was really *wrong*, so I don't think you should have deleted it, but that's up to you.

Comment: @KevinWorkman - don't worry, enjoy the upvotes:)

Comment: I'll echo Kevin, Josh, I liked your answer, it just happens to have been overtaken by one that matched my question more closely. I think that your answer still belongs here as the beauty of the English language is that it is multifaceted - there are at times more scientific words for things that have more accessible words for every day usage.

Comment: "Run for political office" seems to be a popular option these days.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You might be looking for [**eclose**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20ecloses):

> (of an insect) emerge as an adult from the pupa or as a larva from the egg.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pupa#Cocoon), emphasis mine:

> Like other types of pupae, the chrysalis stage in most butterflies is
>   one in which there is little movement. However, some butterfly pupae
>   are capable of moving the abdominal segments to produce sounds or to
>   scare away potential predators. Within the chrysalis, growth and
>   differentiation occur. The adult butterfly emerges (**ecloses**) from this
>   and expands its wings by pumping haemolymph into the wing veins.
>   Although this sudden and rapid change from pupa to imago is often
>   called metamorphosis, metamorphosis is really the whole series of
>   changes that an insect undergoes from egg to adult.

If you do a [google image search of **eclosion**](https://www.google.com/search?q=eclosion&source=lnms&tbm=isch) (the noun form of the verb *eclose*), you get a bunch of pictures of butterflies coming out of cocoons, so I think this is as close as you're going to get.

[image: https://www.google.com/search?q=eclosion&source=lnms&tbm=isch]

**Edit:** [Josh61](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/66974/josh61) has downvoted me for not providing usages from academic contexts (I was unaware that was a requirement on this site, my bad), so here are a couple examples:

[Myers, Edith M. "The circadian control of eclosion." Chronobiology international 20.5 (2003): 775-794.](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/CBI-120024214)

> Eclosion is the stage in development when the adult insect emerges from the shell of its old 
>   cuticle.

[Allada, Ravi, et al. "Stopping time: the genetics of fly and mouse circadian clocks." Annual review of neuroscience 24.1 (2001): 1091-1119.](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.neuro.24.1.1091)

> Fruit flies proceed through a series of characteristic developmental stages, beginning with the embryonic through a series of three larval stages to a pupal stage from which adults emerge or eclose.

You can do a search on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=eclosion) if you really want more.

Comment: Gah - beaten to it by an hour! As a professional entomologist I can confirm that this is the correct technical term.

Comment: The question seems to be asking for a term other than "hatch" to describe the animal leaving the crysalis. This is the right answer IMHO

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a better answer, though the other one was convincing when it was the only answer available. It is strange to me as eclosion is the French term for Hatching.

Comment: @arboviral Every once in a while I daydream about what my life would be like if I had become an entomologist instead of a programmer. Sigh, the road untaken...

Comment: @KevinWorkman It is possible to do both (although not necessarily as much fun as it sounds!) - my job involves some insect population modelling and transmission modelling as well as Bayesian statistical inference. Just spotted the link in your profile - I may come and pick your brains about developing some resources... :)

Comment: Academic context just gives a bit of weight, a "nice to have" from my point of view. It does turn it from a great response to a fantastic answer. Thank you.

Comment: @asoundmove Fair enough. I think the results from Google Scholar are pretty interesting. I would have provided them if the question included a request for scholarly examples!

Comment: @KevinWorkman I would never give up being a programmer to be an entomologist. I deal with enough bugs already, I don't want to deal with even more of them!

Comment: @MKII I wish I could offer a bounty on comments, because that gave me a good laugh. I am definitely stealing that joke from you.

Comment: i do apologize for the intrusion, but what would be the antonym then? the opposite of eclosging-hatching. what is the generic verb of butterfly going into pupa or putting stuff inside an egg? pupate is too specific

Comment: @user151496 Sounds like a job for a new question. Let us know what you find in your research!

Answer (score 9):

I think that ***[hatch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hatch)*** can be used also for cocoons and chrysalises:

> - 1. (Zoology) to cause (the young of various animals, esp birds) to emerge from the egg or (of young birds, etc) to emerge from the egg
> - 2. (Zoology) to cause (eggs) to break and release the fully developed young or (of eggs) to break and release the young animal within

***[How to Hatch a Butterfly Cocoon](http://oaklandcountymoms.com/how-to-hatch-a-butterfly-cocoon-24970/)*** :

> - Hatching and releasing a butterfly from its cocoon is a fun and educational process for kids (and adults) to observe.
> - Creating a safe environment for a cocoon to hatch into a butterfly is very easy. Simply tape a string across a jar full of grass or bucket and hang the cocoon to the string using a separate piece of tape via the string-like substance at the top of the cocoon.

Comment: While I appreciate that some people use hatch in this case, it feels wrong to me - and most of the instances I see describe it as "emerge" or "come out" from the crysalis or cocoon, not as hatch.

All the definitions I saw of hatch mention eggs as the initial state and young as the after state. The coming out of a crysalis or cocoon creates an adult, not a young. Hence my question.

Comment: The link "how to hatch a butterfly cocoon" does not seem to me a very authoritative source. But I appreciate that the English language is defined by usage.

Comment: @asoundmove - it looks like it is quite common though, here it is used in a university context . http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1999-11/942901976.Zo.r.html

Comment: See also here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12089477